# Combining arrays of objects by matching values

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to combine two arrays of objects, to make it easier for me to display in HTML. The function should find matching values of keys called "id" in arr1, and "source" in arr2. Here's what it looks like:

```
   let arr1 = [
   {id = 1,
   name = "Anna"},

   {id = 2,
   name = "Chris"}
   ]

   let arr2 = [
   {childName = "Brian",
   {source = 1}},
   {childName = "Connie",
   {source = 2}}
   {childName = "Dory",
   {source = 1}}
   ]
```

I tried different approaches, with best one being using forEach and filter on the arrays. I'm trying to set up a new property in arr1 objects called "children".

```
  arr1.forEach(el => el.children = arr2.filter(checkMatch));

            function checkMatch(child){
                for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
                    child.childName.source === arr1[i].id
                }
            }
```

And this results in adding appropriate children to the first object(Anna has Brian and Dory now) so it's correct, but it also adds the same children to the second object (so Chris has also Brian and Dory).
Where is my mistake here? I'm guessing that the loop doesn't work the way I want it to work, but I don't know which one and how it happens.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for objects. It should be `id: 1`, not `id = 1`.

Comment: And in `arr2`, `source = 1` shouldn't have another set of `{}` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your syntax for creating the objects of arr1 and arr2 are not valid i tried to guess the structure of your objects.

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Anna"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Chris"
  }
];

let arr2 = [
  {
    childName: "Brian",
    source: 1
  },
  {
    childName: "Connie",
    source: 2
  },
  {
    childName: "Dory",
    source: 1
  }
];

arr2.map((child) => {
  for (let parent of arr1) {
    if (parent.id == child.source) {
      if (!parent.children) {
        parent.children = [];
      }
      parent.children.push(child);
    }
  }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were problems with your JSON, but I tidied and here is option using `map` and `filter`

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Anna"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Chris"
  }];

const arr2 = [{
    childName: "Brian",
    parent: {
      source: 1
    }
  },
  {
    childName: "Connie",
    parent: {
      source: 2
    }
  },
  {
    childName: "Dory", 
    parent: {
      source: 1
    }
  }];

let merge = arr1.map(p => {
  p.children = arr2.filter(c => c.parent.source === p.id).map(c => c.childName);
  return p;
});

console.log(merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json have some problems you should use

> :

instead of

> =

Also some Braces make the structure incorrect, but I think what you want to do here is fill a children sub array with the childNames of the subject here is my approach:

```js
     var json = 
        [
           {
           "id" : 1,
           "name" : "Anna"
           },
           {
           "id" : 2,
           "name" : "Chris"
           }
            ];
             
         var subJson = [
           {
           "childName" : "Brian",
           "source" : 1
           },
           {
           "childName" : "Connie",
           "source" : 2
           },
           {"childName" : "Dory",
           "source" : 1
           }
           ];
        
        var newJson = [];
        $.each(json,function(index1,item){
        newJson.push({"id":item.id,"name":item.name, "children": []});
         $.each(subJson,function(index2,subitem){
         if(subitem.source == item.id){
          newJson[newJson.length - 1].children.push({"childName":subitem.childName}) ;
          }
          })
        })
        
        console.log(newJson);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

The below uses `Map` for storage and convenient lookup of parents.

```
const parents = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Anna"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Chris"
  }
]

const children = [
  {
    childName: "Brian",
    source: 1
  },
  {
    childName: "Connie",
    source: 2
  },
  {
    childName: "Dory",
    source: 1
  }
]

// Create a map for easy lookup of parents.
const parentMap = new Map()

// Add parents to the map, based on their id.
parents.forEach(parent => parentMap.set(parent.id, parent))

// Add children to their parents.
children.forEach((child) => {
  // Get the parent from the map.
  const parent = parentMap.get(child.source)

  // Handle parent not found error.
  if (!parent) { return console.error('parent not found for', child.childName)}

  // Create the children array if it doesn't already exist.
  parent.children = parent.children || []

  // Add the child to the parent's children array.
  parent.children.push(child)
})

// Output the result.
Array.from(parentMap).forEach(parent => console.log(parent[1]))
```

Result:

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  name: 'Anna',
  children: [ 
    { childName: 'Brian', source: 1 },
    { childName: 'Dory', source: 1 } 
  ] 
}
{ 
  id: 2,
  name: 'Chris',
  children: [ 
    { childName: 'Connie', source: 2 } 
  ] 
}
```