# How to list Sub-categories under their Categories if they are both in the same array of objects, by matching values of different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I want to create a dropdown menu from categories and subcategories inside an array of objects that is not organised.

The way to recognise a subcategory is because it has a "parent_id" key. Categories do not.

So ideally, I would like to gather all the objecst with the same "parent_id", under their parent category with matching "_id"

sub categories look like this:

```js
{
"_id": "69",
"name": "Breads",
"parent_id": "60",
"product_skus": [],
},
```

and the parent category looks like this:

```js
{
"_id": "60",
"name": "Bakery",
"product_skus": [],
},
```

I am a beginner, so I may be using the wrong logic. This is what I have so far:

```js
import data from "./data.json";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((each, index) => {
        let category = "";
        let categoryID = "";
        let subCategory = "";
        let subCategoryID = "";

        if (!each.parent_id) {
          category = each.name;
          categoryID = each._id;
        } else {
          subCategory = each.name;
          subCategoryID = each.parent_id;
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{category}</h1>
            <p>{subCategory}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

** But I am missing a tool to group them together by id**
In other words this is the part that I can't make work yet:

```js
if(categoryID === subCategoryID){
return (
          <div>
            <h1>{category}</h1>
            <p>{subCategory}</p>
          </div>
        );
}
```

Thanks, its a long way to get to this:

[image: The final result]

**Sample data: 2 categories in here with corresponding subCategories**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5f1",
    "name": "Chocolat en Poudre",
    "slug": "cafe-the-chocolat-chocolat-en-poudre",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5ad",
    "product_skus": [
      "14001104",
      "14002219",
      "14001109",
      "14002218",
      "14000754",
      "14002217"
    ],
    "rank": 14
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b57b",
    "name": "Cafés Moulus",
    "slug": "cafe-the-chocolat-cafes-moulus",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5ad",
    "product_skus": ["14001050", "14003114", "14001900", "14001047"],
    "rank": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5ad",
    "name": "Café, Thé & Chocolat",
    "slug": "cafe-the-chocolat",
    "product_skus": [],
    "rank": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b58b",
    "name": "Capsules Compatibles Nespresso",
    "slug": "cafe-the-chocolat-capsules-compatible-nespresso",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5ad",
    "product_skus": [
      "14003149",
      "14003140",
      "14003144",
      "14003143",
      "14003141",
      "14003148",
      "14003146",
      "14001894"
    ],
    "rank": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5b7",
    "name": "Dosettes Tassimo",
    "slug": "cafe-the-chocolat-dosettes-tassimo",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5ad",
    "product_skus": ["14003102", "14003104"],
    "rank": 7
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b625",
    "name": "Desserts aux Fruits",
    "slug": "yaourts-et-desserts-desserts-aux-fruits",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5f0",
    "product_skus": [
      "14003663",
      "14002031",
      "14000403",
      "14002036",
      "14002016",
      "14002030",
      "14002037",
      "14002035",
      "14000414",
      "14002034",
      "14003673",
      "14000412",
      "14003675",
      "14002033",
      "14003672",
      "14003674",
      "14002017"
    ],
    "rank": 60
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5f0",
    "name": "Yaourts & Desserts",
    "slug": "yaourts-et-desserts",
    "product_skus": [],
    "rank": 13
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5dd",
    "name": "Yaourts à Boire",
    "slug": "yaourts-et-desserts-yaourts-a-boire",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5f0",
    "product_skus": [
      "14001981",
      "14001982",
      "14001645",
      "14001650",
      "14001980",
      "14001651",
      "14001979"
    ],
    "rank": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5fe",
    "name": "Yaourts",
    "slug": "yaourts-et-desserts-yaourts",
    "parent_id": "6181841060c425f76e57b5f0",
    "product_skus": ["14001991", "14000363", "14000367"],
    "rank": 20
  }
]
```

Comment: can you post the mock data so that I could answer clearly

Comment: Thank you. I have pasted some of the data☝

Comment: You may want to consider using an `Object` which can be generated from your data-array. The key may be category-id of only those elements which have no `parent_id`. And the value may be the parent-object as-is with one additional prop, say `subCategories` which may be an array of those elements which are having `parent_id` matching the key. Then, all you need to do is render by iterating over the keys of this new object. All your necessary data will be neatly grouped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The perfect answer was found here:
[answer from @Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246834/4134752)

Where he abstracts an array (arr1) into a parent/child relationship as such into a new array (arr2):

```js
arr2.map((child) => {
  for (let parent of arr1) {
    if (parent.id == child.source) {
      if (!parent.children) {
        parent.children = [];
      }
      parent.children.push(child);
    }
  }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

applying this to my original question results in 28 categories (parent) with over 130 sub categories (child) nested.

```js
function App() {
  let mainCategories = [];
  let subCategories = [];

//this is to filter and separate

  data.map((each, index) => {
    if (!each.parent_id && !each.is_special) {
      mainCategories.push(each);
    } else if (each.parent_id && !each.is_special) {
      subCategories.push(each);
    }
  });

/* This is how we map through the sub-categories and 
if their 'parent_id' match the '_id' of the parent 
category, then we that object to the mainCategories 
inside a new key called 'sub'*/

  subCategories.map((sub) => {
    for (let category of mainCategories) {
      if (category._id == sub.parent_id) {
        if (!category.sub) {
          category.sub = [];
        }
        category.sub.push(sub);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(mainCategories);

  return <p>{mainCategories[1].sub[0].name}</p>;
}

export default App;
```

[image: Console log]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).